# Djangdo 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute '_stream'

Tags: django, stream, httprequest

I create an instance of HttpRequest to test my restful "PUT" method. 
In oder to set the request body like {"active":true}, I write:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
request=HttpRequest()
request.method='PUT'
request.content_type='application/json'
request.POST["active"]=True        
response=views.job(request,job_name='TestJob')
```

The last line calls the "PUT" method and brings the error. Why has my 'HttpRequest' object no attribute '_stream'? How can I set the attribute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because HttpRequest is the abstraction of an **incoming request**. If you want to make requests, use the [test Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).